# annoying libv8 error even after successful install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bundler, libv8

okay. I am trying bootstarp for the first time and I added gems "therubyracer" and "less-rails" to my gemfile along with 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'. After

> bundle install

I get following error.

```
Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /home/addie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/cache/libv8-3.16.14.3-x86_64-linux.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

as it says, I tried:

> gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'

and it does succeeds.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed libv8-3.16.14.3
Parsing documentation for libv8-3.16.14.3
Done installing documentation for libv8 after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

but when I try bundle install again, I get the same error as before:

```
Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /home/addie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/cache/libv8-3.16.14.3-x86_64-linux.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Its so annoying! Can someone please help me?

EDIT:

As most of the solution to libv8 questions suggest, I tried

> gem install libv8 -v '3.11.8.17' -- --with-system-v8

it succeeds too but makes no difference to bundle install error.

Comment: What's the output of `gem list | grep libv`

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

1. Remove current `libv8` version

   gem uninstall libv8
2. Re-install `libv8`

   gem install libv8
3. Check new version number

   gem list | grep libv
4. Update `Gemfile` to the installed version of `libv8` obtained from (3) above

   gem 'libv8', '3.11.8.3' #for example
5. Try bundling again

   bundle install

Comment: Sorry! Too impatient to sit around for solution. I uninstalled rails and installed it again and it worked. I think there was something wrong with path bundler was using or something. thanks anyway!